# where are my emails of 2004-7?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

How can I find email older than 10 years in Gmail? I need my messages since the beginning; I guess 2003 or 2004. I see only since 2007!

Comment: Gmail was launched in 2004 and wasn't available to everyone. Unless you've imported mail from elsewhere, you won't _have_ messages from 2003.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure haven't deleted it before.

No reason not to find the emails!

What happens when you enter `after:2003/1/1 before:2006/12/30` in the search bar?

No results?!

Answer (score 0):

Look in "all mail"

- click on the "all mail" label in the list of labels.
- In the upper right corner you will see a clickable item "1-100 of xx,xxx"
- click on that item and select oldest.
- you will now see the oldest messages you have in Gmail.

If there is nothing before 2007, then those were deleted at some point.